# Adding authentication header to HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to access an API, but all the documentation is in PHP and I'm not very familiar with PHP. I am having trouble authenticating to the API. The [documentation is here](https://xboxapi.com/documentation).

Here is what I have so far

```
var webAddress = "https://xboxapi.com/v2/latest-xbox360-games";

var httpResponse = (new HttpClient().GetAsync(webAddress)).Result;
httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var jsonResponse = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I'm just not sure how to add the authentication header that they are using in PHP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a custom header (in this case `X-AUTH`), you need to send a custom `HttpRequestMessage`.  For example:

```
var webAddress = "https://xboxapi.com/v2/latest-xbox360-games";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, webAddress);
msg.Headers.Add('X-AUTH', 'your-auth-key-here');

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(msg);
```

Comment: In addition to the above you can also add the header directly onto the HttpClient if your reusing the HttpClient object HttpClient client = new HttpClient();            
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-AUTH", "your-auth-key-here");